# Python GUI Word Guessing Game

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I'm trying to build a GUI word guess game using tkinter. I'm receiving an **UnboundLocalError: local variable 'guesses' referenced before assignment** for the line 'if guess.get() in guesses:'.

I have this at the top of my code:

```
global guesses
guesses = []
```

And this is the function that is throwing the error:

```
def play():
    while remaining.get() > 0:
        if guess.get().isalpha() == False or len(guess.get()) != 1:
            output.set('Invalid input. Please enter a letter from a-z.')
        else:
            if guess.get() in guesses:
                output.set('That letter has already been guessed!')
            else:
                if guess.get() not in secret_word:
                    output.set('That letter does not occur in the secret word.')
                else:
                    output.set('That is a good guess! ' + str(guess.get()) + ' occurs ' + \
                        str(countOccurences(str(secret_word), guess.get())) + ' time(s) in the secret word')
                    guesses += guess.get()
                    remaining.set(remaining.get() - 1)

        if '_' not in getHint(secret_word, guesses):
            result.set('Congratulations! You guessed the secret word: ' + str(secret_word))
            break

    if remaining == 0:
        result = 'Sorry, the secret word was: ' + str(secret_word)
```

I've changed where guesses is scope-wise, I've redefined it multiple times and nothing has worked. I'm not sure what else to do to prevent this error.

Any help would be extremely appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `global` keyword in the methods that need to use the global variable.

That is, put `global guesses` **inside** the `play()` method, instead of outside it.

```
guesses = []
...
def play():
    global guesses
    while remaining.get() > 0:
        if guess.get().isalpha() == False or len(guess.get()) != 1:  
            ....
```

Don't get too comfortable using this though. As you get more experienced with Python, at some point you will probably want to use classes to store and access variables that need to be shared between methods.

Finally, for future questions here, please consider using a title that pinpoints the actual problem instead of your broader intentions. You'll be more likely to receive helpful answers that way!